# Get ADUser sort by memberof not working for me

Tags: powershell, active-directory, memberof

I've a need to extract a list of all members in a particular OU who are members of the same group. Problem is it only works if I use -match, however that also picks up groups that have a similar name. If I use -eq it retrieves nothing, despite users being members of that particular group. Anyone who might be able to help me figure what I'm doing wrong?

The powershell script I've been using;

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=NewUsers,DC=LOCAL' -properties memberof | Where-Object {$_.memberof -eq 'APP-KMD'} | Select SamAccountName
```

Comment: `$_.memberof -eq 'APP-KMD'` --> `$_.memberof -like '*APP-KMD*'`

Comment: This one sadly overmatches as well, taking other groups with it as well. Example "APP-KMD_Test"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can't match directly, but if you grab the matches on the given group and pull out the members of that group and compare them, it gives the expected output.

```
$brugere = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=NewUsers,DC=LOCAL' -Properties * | Select-Object SamAccountName
$gruppemedlem = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity app-kmd | select SamAccountName

ForEach ($bruger in $brugere)
{   

If ($gruppemedlem.samaccountname -contains $bruger.SamAccountName) {
    Write-Host $bruger }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is with the comparison Operator, here are some of the Differences between these:

Number Comparison:

- eq (equal to)
- ne (not equal to)
- gt (greater than)
- lt (less than)
- le (less than or equal to)
- ge (greater than or equal to)

String Comparison:

- -like and -notLike (wildcard string comparison, wildcards being * and ?), not to be confused with the -contains operator.

Regex Comparison

- -match and -notMatch (Matching with regular expressions)

If you know the exact name of the Group you should probably use -like "GROUPNAME", this way you get only the Users of this group.

Comment: -like doesn't return the users either. It's weird because if I use -match, the users in the group get on the list, along with the other similar named groups.

Comment: If it almost works with match, I can suggest you reading This: [RegEx Formatting](https://dl.icewarp.com/online_help/203030104.htm) In your case, you should be safe if you put ^ at the start and $ at the end of the Groupname.

Comment: Just tested with both ^ and $ in front and end and one without the other. It still refused to extract my matches. Thanks for the quick answers though.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the value of `memberOf` attribute is a DN of a group, so you need to match with whole DN, not just CN of the group. You may get the DN of a group in a subquery and use it directly in a filter, i.e.:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(memberof=$(Get-ADGroup APP-KMD))" -SearchBase 'OU=NewUsers,DC=LOCAL' | Select SamAccountName
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post, I know, but just wanted to throw my hat into the ring for others.

Maybe I missed something, but wouldn't it just be simpler to pipe `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "APP-KMD"` through to `Get-ADUser`?

```
$ADUserParameters = 
@{
   "SearchBase" = "OU=NewUsers,DC=LOCAL"
   "Properties" = "SamAccountName"
   "Filter" = "*"
}
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "APP-KMD" | Get-ADUser @ADUserParameters
```

Not exactly sure it's the most performant code, but it's at least limiting what you're sending through the pipeline to only members of that group, vs. all members of `Get-ADUser` through the entire SearchBase first.

EDIT: Disregard, it's waaay more performant to use -LDAPFilter as someone else pointed out - the following worked for me.

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(memberof=$(get-adgroup 'YOUR-SEC-GROUP'))"
```

OR for better maintainability

```
$secGroup = Get-ADGroup "YOUR-SEC-GROUP"
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(memberof=$secGroup)"
```